# Как добавить html код в уже существующем html файле

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема, при записи html-тегов в файл)
У меня в сервере есть статический html file.
после последней `<tr>...</tr>` хочу добавить такой же html элемент
Содержание примерно такое

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>`
<tr>...</tr>
```

как мне найти последний `<tr>...</tr>`, а после него добавить свой?

Comment: Если вопрос по регуляркам и весь текст в переменной - то ответ таков `/(.*<\/tr>)(.*?)/s` НО, это запись выражения из перла, которая просто выделяет все что ДО (включая последний </tr>) и ПОСЛЕ. Между ними не проблема вставить все что угодно. Причем `s` в конце - это флаг, говорящий перлу, что надо учитывать переводы каретки как обычные символы. В других языках флаги часто есть, но  задаются по другому. А вообще в C гораздо дешевле искать строковыми функциями типа `strstr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статический файл? Допишите в него строку `<!-- add here -->` в то место, где надо добавлять, ищите её и добавляйте вместо неё свой код.

А вообще, вы изобретаете <s>велосипед</s> шаблонизатор.

(И почитайте про [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ruscottgu/razor) на досуге.)